# Get a item from list click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have this view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfissionalEmpresaResultadoView: View {
    @Binding var profissionais: [ProfissionalEmpresaModel]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView
        {
            List{
                ForEach(profissionais, id: \.self){ profissional in
                    ItemProfissionalEmpresaGridView(profissional: profissional)
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i click some row in this list and get one `profissional` item on click?

Comment: Add onTapGesture modifier inside ForEach

Comment: Put your view inside the button lable. you will get button effect too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onTapGesture`

```
ItemProfissionalEmpresaGridView(profissional: profissional).onTapGesture {
    print(profissional)
}
```